# Resize video.js based on window size

Tags: javascript, reactjs, video.js

I have implemented [video.js](https://videojs.com/) in a React app. I have created this video component following the official [documentation](https://docs.videojs.com/tutorial-react.html):

```
import React from "react";
import videojs from "video.js";

export default class VideoPlayer extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    window.addEventListener("resize", this.onResize);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // instantiate Video.js
    this.player = videojs(this.videoNode, this.props, function onPlayerReady() {
      console.log("onPlayerReady", this);
    });
  }

  // destroy player on unmount
  componentWillUnmount() {
    if (this.player) {
      this.player.dispose();
    }
  }

  // wrap the player in a div with a `data-vjs-player` attribute
  // so videojs won't create additional wrapper in the DOM
  // see https://github.com/videojs/video.js/pull/3856
  render() {
    return (
      <div
        style={{
          display: "flex",
          justifyContent: "center",
          alignItems: "center"
        }}
      >
        <div data-vjs-player>
          <video
            id="videoPlayer"
            ref={node => (this.videoNode = node)}
            className="video-js"
          ></video>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  onResize() {
    var player = videojs("videoPlayer");
    if (player) {
      player.height = window.innerHeight;
      player.width = window.innerWidth;
    }
  }
}
```

The only thing that I have added is a listener to respond to window changes, the onResize() method at the end.

The problem is that this method is not working, the player reference is working ok, but the player is not responding to any change I am doing in that method. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just a guess here, but could you call the player in onResize() with this.player instead of videojs("videoPlayer")? It seems to me you are not pointing to the right player when resizing.

Comment: That's what I tried at the beggining @btnhawk, I am doing that way because this.player is undefined on that method...I don't know why...but yeah, maybe the issue is related to not selecting the correct player...

Answer (score 0):

`height` and `width` are methods, not properties. `player.height(n)`